# AlertDialog blocks Espresso Test Execution

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso

During my Espresso test execution and AlertDialog is prompted and waiting for user respond. The Espresso test only continues if I press the "Accept" button but I want to test to do this event instead of the user.

```
@Test
protected void testLogin() {
    Log.d(TAG,"testLogin");

    onView(withId(R.id.et_user)).perform(clearText())
            .perform(replaceText(USER),
                    pressImeActionButton(),
                    closeSoftKeyboard());

    onView(withId(R.id.et_passwd)).perform(clearText())
            .perform(replaceText(PASSWD), closeSoftKeyboard());

    onView(withId(R.id.bt_login)).perform(click());

    // Here is where it stops until I click accept on the alert dialog

}
```

**UPDATE**
Also I noticed on my Thread Tab the following status

Android JUnit Runner thread while is running
[image: My Android JUnit Runner thread while is running]

Android JUnit Runner thread after the AlertDialog is shown
[image]

Comment: I think you are having trouble finding that "Accept" button from your espresso test. Like @Sharj suggested below, you could try `onView(withText("Accept")).perform(click());`

Comment: No, I'm not. If that were the case, the Running Test at least would failed or succeed. But it just stays stuck right before any other perform or check statement is execute. Sorry, I could not share anymore detailed code.

Answer (score 0):

First you can test if your AlertDialog is visible by checking text in your dialog:

```
onView(withText("Your text in the dialog, such as title or message")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

If it's a regular AlertDialog then its positive button will have id `android.R.id.button1` so you can press it in your test like this:

```
onView(withId(android.R.id.button1)).perform(click());
```

Comment: The problem is that the test stops just right before `onView(withText("Your text in the dialog, such as title or message")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));`